# cleverhans - tf2 implementation of momentum_iterative_method has an inconsistency with the algorithm from the paper

Tags: cleverhans

tf2 implementation of momentum_iterative_method：
line 93 of momentum_iterative_method.py use “tf.math.***reduce_mean***(tf.math.abs(grad), red_ind, keepdims=True)” for updating the grad.

but in the paper:
Algorithm 1 uses L1 norm (***reduce_sum***()).

So, is this a mistake? or better using ***reduce_mean***() here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code of MI-FSGM in cleverhans is here : [link](https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans/tf2/attacks/momentum_iterative_method.py). You can find that the implementation `grad = grad / tf.math.maximum(
            avoid_zero_div,
            tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.abs(grad), red_ind, keepdims=True),
        )` to update the gradient, which is different from the Algorithm 1 from the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.06081.pdf). You can find in  Algorithm 1, it use L1 norm to update the gradient.